# JQuery Showing Table By Number

Tags: jquery, hide

I have 8 tables all with the same name with exception of a number.

```
Example:
table_1
table_2
table_3
.
.
table_8
```

How can I hide the table according to a variable with a number 1 trough 8.

Example:

```
$("#table_number").show();
```

I would like that number to be a variable which I specify.

Is it possible what I want to do or too complex to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a string with the number in a variable.

```
var identifier = "#table_"+num;
$(identifier).hide();
```

Where the variable num is the number of the table you want to hide.

Comment: Or even just: `$("#table_"+num).hide();` :)

Comment: ... Just make very sure you have tight control over num.  If you happen to be getting it from the URL, you'll be in trouble if a malicious user sets num to something like `<img src=0 onerror=alert(42)>`!  (i.e. you'll have made your site vulnerable to an XSS attack).  You can verify this is an issue by running `javascript:var num="<img src=0 onerror=alert(42)>";$("#table_"+num);` on a jQuery enabled site like this one.